# Specific Web Font is not showing on Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, webfonts

In this site I am currently coding Im using webfonts that are stored on my server.
Every browser displays them just fine but not chrome.
Chrome uses Times New Roman instead.
After checking the developer tools on chrome I found that they fonts ARE being requested from the server and retreived successfully.
For some reason, Chrome wont use them.
I did notice that if I install the fonts on my computer (Using Windows, BTW), the suddenly work on chrome aswell.

Here's my font-face decleration:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BNLunch';
    src: url('BN_Lunch.eot');
    src: url('BN_Lunch.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('BN_Lunch.woff') format('woff'),
         url('BN_Lunch.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('BN_Lunch.svg#BNLunchregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Any insights?

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that this particular CSS works with other fonts.
Only this particular font and BNMadregot are giving me trouble.
Could it be that it is because the English letters of this font are blank?

Comment: If this is a problem with a specific font, then you should identify the font that makes it possible to others to access the font.

Comment: Im sorry I didnt quite understand what I should do?..

Comment: Specify the proper name of the font, its creator, and where it is available from, and how you created the .woff and other files (or got them from). Adding a URL of a demo would help a lot, too. How do you expect others to help you with a problem that is specifically about one font, without knowing even what font it is?

Comment: The url of the font is: http://www.ph4.ru/dlfont.php?s=BN_Lunch&b=ttf&c=ttf-hebrew
and I used http://www.font-face-generator.com/ to create the woff file.
the site http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator said that the original font file is corrupted and wouldn't create the woff file.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar CSS code here that works fine on every browser, even Chrome.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "standard 07_58";
    src: url("../fonts/standard_07_58/stan0758.eot?") format("eot"),
         url("../fonts/standard_07_58/stan0758.woff") format("woff"),
         url("../fonts/standard_07_58/stan0758.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("../fonts/standard_07_58/stan0758.svg#Standard0758") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

There are some differences from your CSS, so try to follow this pattern and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The font is broken (as FontSquirrel told you). Don’t use it. I downloaded BN Lunch from the site you mentioned and processed it with font-face-generator.com, and test .html page it generated does not show characters in that font (and yes, I tried common digits and Hebrew letters, too) on Chrome *or* on Firefox, only on IE (tested on Win 7). Chrome dev tools shows that Chrome gets the font files and does not signal errors, so apparently the internal tables of the font are broken (e.g., giving wrong information about character coverage). The site that distributes it looks suspiciously like one of the many illegal font distribution sites; e.g., authors or copyright holders of fonts are not mentioned.

So, get another font.